# Soundcloud Javascript SDK 3.0 - Callback cannot read property 'connectCallback' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

I'm trying to do basic authentication with the javascript SDK.

***callback.html***

```html
<!DOCTPYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
        <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my script to call it:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: /*MY CLIENT ID*/,
    redirect_uri: 'http://www.sc-app.co.nf/callback.html'
});

function connectSC() {
SC.connect().then(function () {
    return SC.get('/me');
}).then(function (me) {
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
});
}
```

Checking the console logs it always shows
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectCallback' of undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Insert on head

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know see: Error: Permission denied to access property "SC"